# mySQL INSERT while making sure a specific column has one "YES" value and the rest "NO"

Tags: php, sql, insert, unique

I have a table: event_list with two columns: name as var(80) and default as ENUM('y','n').

The idea is that there can only be one event set as default at a time. So if there are 100 events in the table 99 of them must have a default value of 'n' and one must have a default value of 'y'.

When a customer is adding a new event to the system there is a option "Make This Event Default". What I want to do is insert the event into the table. If the default column for that insert is added as 'y' I need a easy way of changing all the rest of the default rows to 'n'.

Is there a way for mySQL to handle this or will I have to manually change all the other data fields to 'n' if the user makes a new default?

Comment: Perhaps a rearchitecting is called for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest altering your current table to include an ID (unique, autoincrement) field, and removing the enum field, and then adding a new table that stores the ID of default event.  Then you only need to edit one line.

Comment: In the new table, you might want to create constraints to guarantee that there is only one row in the table. For example, create table DefID(default_id int not null foreign key references yourT(id), enforcer int not null unique default(0) check (enforcer=0)) You can also use the same sort of constraints to do this without another table, if you use 'y' and NULL instead of 'y' and 'n' in the main table. Note that neither of these solutions (nor SenorAmor's guarantees that there is an event that is marked as the default event.

Comment: So silly of me! That makes so much sense, I should have thought if it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SteveKass: Off course there is no (declarative) way to guarantee that there is an event that is marked as the default event.

Comment: Alright, now I just need to figure out how to insert to my event_list table and update to the event_default table with the id of the recently inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it using a trigger.
Else, you'll have to update all your records to set there status to 'n' prior to do your insert.

edit : SenorAmor answer looks better

Answer (score 0):

how about creating `STORED PROCEDURE`?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SetCurrentEvent(IN oEventName varchar(50))
BEGIN
     UPDATE `event_list` SET `default` = 'N';
     UPDATE `event_list` SET `default` = 'Y' WHERE `name` = oEventName;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So by creating this, you can simply use:

```
CALL SetCurrentEvent('qwwrty');
```

Comment: That's really good actually. I'm going to keep note if this technique. Although I think this time around I'm going to go with the new table idea.